# Is it allowed to write $\Sigma\tau = I\alpha$ as $\Sigma\vec{\tau} = I\vec{\alpha}$?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, vectors, torque

Is it allowed to write the rotational form of Newton's 2nd law, $\Sigma\tau = I\alpha$ as $\Sigma\vec{\tau} = I\vec{\alpha}$? The textbook that I am using (HRK) never adds vector signs as above, so I worry that there is some underlying reasons that makes doing so invalid.

For example, in the following solution to a problem in the textbook. Shouldn't the $\alpha$ in the highlighted equations have a vector sign as I added in red?

[image]

Comment: $\alpha_z$ is the $z$-component of the angular acceleration, so it's not a vector and it's not correct to notate it as a vector.

Comment: @d_b Why isn't the component of a vector also a vector itself? If the components aren't vectors, it seems to me that they would not be able to make up another vector (since there's no direction information)

Comment: The components are numbers that multiply unit vectors to give a vector. So for example $\vec{\alpha} = \alpha_x \hat{x} + \alpha_y \hat{y} + \alpha_z \hat{z}$. The direction information is contained in the unit vectors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, **yes** the vector equation you wrote is correct, that is $\sum_i\vec{\tau}_i= I \vec{\alpha}$ (where $\vec{\tau}_i$ are the potentially multiple torques acting on an object, and $\vec{\alpha}$ is the angular acceleration of that object).

However, as d_b noted in the comment, $\alpha_z$ is the component of a vector and not a vector itself. If you want a vector quantity (and assuming the angular acceleration only has a component in the $z$-direction), you can write $\vec{\alpha}=\frac{-a_{cm}}{R}\hat{e}_z$ where $\hat{e}_z$ is the unit vector in the $z$-direction (also often denoted $\hat{\mathbf{k}}$ or $\hat{\mathbf{z}}$).

Then the final equation would also be vectorial, so
$$\vec{f} = \frac{I_{cm}}{R}\vec{\alpha}$$.

---

In response to your comment:
The components of a vector aren't vectors because they don't have a direction. A vector lives in a vector space which has basis vectors, in Cartesian coordinates, for example, the basis vectors are $$\hat{\mathbf{x}}=\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}, \hat{\mathbf{y}}=\begin{pmatrix}0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}, \hat{\mathbf{z}}=\begin{pmatrix}0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$$
A vector in this space is a linear combination of basis vectors, which means that any vector $\mathbf{v}$ can be written as $\mathbf{v} = a_x\hat{\mathbf{x}} + a_y \hat{\mathbf{y}} + a_z\hat{\mathbf{z}}$ where the $a$'s are what I'm calling the "components" of the vector. So the components aren't vectors, they are just numbers that you can multiply with vectors. However if you have a component together with its basis vector (as described in my main answer above), you *do* get a vector because (number $\times$ vector) is a vector.

Comment: What does the index represent in the torque equation there? If you're summing over $i$ on the left side, there should be no $i$ on the right side.

Comment: Thanks, fixed. I'm assuming that in the question the sum is a sum over individual/independent torques acting on an object.

Comment: Why isn't the component of a vector also a vector itself? If the components aren't vectors, it seems to me that they would not be able to make up another vector (since there's no direction information)

Comment: This is really a separate question, but I've tried to roughly answer it in my edited answer above.